# JOIN to second database whose name is stored in the first in a SINGLE query

Tags: mysql, join, mariadb

I can `SELECT` data from two databases (with the appropriate user permissions) as so:

```
SELECT * 
FROM test1.table1 AS t1 
INNER JOIN test2.table2 AS t2 ON (t2.id = t1.id);
```

That will return the following results:

```
+----+-------+----+------------------------------------------+
| id | db    | id | info                                     |
+----+-------+----+------------------------------------------+
| 1  | test2 | 1  | Success if test2 db name was not static. |
+----+-------+----+------------------------------------------+
```

However I need to change `INNER JOIN test2.table2` to use the database specified in `test1.table1.db` in a single query. The `db` can dynamically change per `JOIN` so I can not write it beforehand.

How do I use a database name stored as a row value to `JOIN` two databases using a single query?

Unfortunately I'm not in the privileged position to debate the merit of this. Also I've tried a couple MariaDB fiddles and both didn't work so here is the test code I'm working with:

Database `test1`:

```
CREATE DATABASE `test1` /*!40100 COLLATE 'utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci' */

CREATE TABLE `table1` (`id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`db` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci', PRIMARY KEY (`id`) USING BTREE)
COLLATE='utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB;

INSERT INTO `table1` (`id`, `db`) VALUES (1, 'test2');
```

Database `test2`:

```
CREATE DATABASE `test2` /*!40100 COLLATE 'utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci' */

CREATE TABLE `table2` (`id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`info` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci', PRIMARY KEY (`id`) USING BTREE)
COLLATE='utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci' ENGINE=InnoDB;

INSERT INTO `table2` (`id`, `info`) VALUES (1, 'Success if test2 db name was not static.');
```

Comment: Why do you have two databases?

Comment: `Unfortunately I'm not in the privileged position to debate the merit of this.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed a prepared statement. For the less experienced all of this will work in a *single* query to the database and allow the ability to dynamically `JOIN` two databases.

```
SET @db = (SELECT db FROM test1.table1);

PREPARE stmt FROM CONCAT('SELECT * FROM test1.table1 AS t1 INNER JOIN ', @db, '.table2 AS t2 ON (t2.id = t1.id)');

EXECUTE stmt;

DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Comment: How is this 1 query? You're doing exactly what @Jeff describes in their answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this, unfortunately.

You'll have to query the database name out by querying Table1, then dynamically build the query using that database name, and execute the second query separately.

Comment: I have to respectfully disagree. It's been a while though there are **prepared statements** which allow exactly the kind of thing I'm trying to do in a single query from the scripting language to the database. I'll post the answer after I get the old documentation working.

Comment: I stand corrected, thanks for teaching me something new!